# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet [<Store: X-Clusive Store>, <Store: GenFliX Exception Store>]>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Helo dev, can someone help me with this small but big problem. it returns this field id erro when a user create two store and try to add items to that store. if it is a single store, everything goes well and no erro will show but when the user create a store and try to add item to it, that is when this occurs.

```
def itemupload(request):
    user = request.user
    items = Items.objects.filter(user_id = request.user)
    
    
    try:
        # store = Store.objects.get(author= user)
        store = Store.objects.filter(author= user)
        
    except Store.DoesNotExist:
        store = None
        
   
    if request.method =='POST':
        itemsforms =ItemsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        imageforms = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        
        file= request.FILES.getlist('image')
       
        if all([itemsforms.is_valid(), imageforms.is_valid()]):

            item = itemsforms.save(commit = False)
            item.user = request.user
            item.save()
            item.store.add(store)
            
            for i in file:
                Images.objects.create(item = item, image =i)
           
            return redirect('index')
        return redirect('itemupload')
        
    imageforms =ImageForm()
    itemsforms = ItemsForm()
    context = {
        'imageforms': imageforms,
        'itemsform':itemsforms,
        'items':items,
    }
    return render(request, 'jijiapp/itemform.html', context)
```

this is model.py

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(unique =True, max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    discription=models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    location =models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    logo =models.ImageField(upload_to='logos/', default = '')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Store'

class Items(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    store = models.ManyToManyField(Store)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank =True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    location =models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnails =models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering =['-post_date',]
        verbose_name_plural ='Items'
```

this is the traceback

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 18, 2023 - 05:34:16
Django version 4.0, using settings 'jijiclone.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
tiis is the <generator object itemupload.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x00000248939D25F0> and the is <QuerySet [<Store: X-Clusive Store>, <Store: GenFliX Exception Store>]>
Internal Server Error: /home/itemupload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1822, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QuerySet'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\jijiclone\jijiapp\views.py", line 74, in itemupload
    item.store.add(store)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 949, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1125, in _add_items
    target_ids = self._get_target_ids(target_field_name, objs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1072, in _get_target_ids
    target_ids.add(target_field.get_prep_value(obj))
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 998, in get_prep_value
    return self.target_field.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1824, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet [<Store: X-Clusive Store>, <Store: GenFliX Exception Store>]>.
[18/Mar/2023 05:35:26] "POST /home/itemupload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 94474
```

Comment: `ImageForm` definition seems to be forgotten to be put into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`store` is not a single store, it is a collection of `Store`s, and in this case two `Store`s.

You unpack thus the queryset in the `store`:

```
def itemupload(request):
    items = Items.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    stores = Store.objects.filter(author=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        itemsform = ItemsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        imageform = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        file = request.FILES.getlist('image')

        if itemsform.is_valid() and imageform.is_valid():
            imteform.instance.user = request.user
            item = itemsform.save()
            item.store.add(*stores)

            for i in file:
                Images.objects.create(item=item, image=i)

            return redirect('index')
    else:
        imageform = ImageForm()
        itemsform = ItemsForm()
    context = {
        'imageforms': imageforms,
        'itemsform': itemsforms,
        'items': items,
    }
    return render(request, 'jijiapp/itemform.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Item` instead of <s>`Items`</s>.

Comment: But the challenge is that when I add item to one store it save in all the stores that belongs to the user.  I want to save each store of the user individually